# datetime operation works in notebook but not after export as .py script

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have created a .py file after testing this piece of code on jupyter ipython notebook, which worked well for me.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
def CheckTrend(tdate, px, trend, df):
    todaydate =  dt.datetime.strptime(tdate,'%m/%d/%Y')
    todaydate =  todaydate - dt.timedelta(days=6)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')    
    mask = df['Date'] <= todaydate)        
    df = df.loc[mask]  
    return
```

However when I downloaded it as trend.py file and tried to call from another notebook to test, it fails to work and give me error message -

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

In the notebook, I wrote -

```
import trend
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_csv(filelocation, na_values=['na'], delimiter='\t', usecols=['Date','Type','Trend','Px'])      
trend.CheckTrend('12/31/2006', 10, 0, df)
```

I am a beginner of Python programming, can I get some help on this ?

Comment: what's the filelocation?

Comment: file location is just the same folder i saw all the script where it contains a csv file holding the dataframe data. i tried to print out the dataframe before calling the CheckTrend function and the data looks perfect, so definitely the read_csv was processed without problem.

Answer (score 0):

That seems slightly strange, perhaps try modifying the 'trend' file so that the line
`todaydate =  todaydate - dt.timedelta(days=6)`

becomes

`todaydate =  int(todaydate) - int(dt.timedelta(days=6))`

I'm not sure you'll need the second int around timedelta, but I think that should fix it because it seems to be treating 'todaydate' as a string

Comment: just tried, still getting the same error and it was pointing to this row, which I don't quite understand why, cause the error msg text seems to be pointing to the row of subtraction instead of this parsing line. 

todaydate =  dt.datetime.strptime(tdate,'%m/%d/%Y')